# Android Testing App Error

Tags: android, testing

I am completely new to this, and I know the answer to my question is probably very simple. However, I just can't find it.
I get through the whole `helloworld` tutorial, and when I try to run the app, I get the following message:

> > invalid command-line parameter: Files.
> >     Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
> >     please use -help for more information

Note - I've tried to run this on API 11, 12, and 13.  I know the recommended API is 7, but I can't seem to access 2.0.  I apologize if this question is vague.
If so, I would appreciate any suggestions and try to narrow down what I mean.  Thank you.

Comment: what platform is this? From your name I'd guess you're talking about android? If so please indicate that this question is pertaining to android sdk or whatever you're using

Comment: Yes, I am using Android.  Don't know how I could have left that out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using a command line interface to launch your emulator

If you are using eclipse it may be worth looking in Window>>Android SDK and AVD Manager and checking to see if you have any virtual devices listed.  If none are listed then press new to create a new one. The target shouldn't matter too much

You can then run your app straight from eclipse by right click>>Run As>>Android Application

For extra style points go into run config for your app and set target to manual.  This means that you get to pick the version of android you run on whenever you start the app. This is helpful later on when you want to test on a wide range of devices.